# How to clear Flutter's Build cache?

Tags: dart, flutter

There seems to be a problem with flutter's build.

I always need to perform **RUN** > **Flutter Full Restart** everytime I run the app to an emulator or device.

Otherwise, the app loads a scaffold body which my code had from 2 weeks ago when I first started coding it.

[Here's the current source on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/m62M7TTy)

```
children: <Widget>[
          new Opacity(
              opacity: loader_visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              child:
              new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator()
              )
          ),
```

while here is the resulting render tree:
[image: while here is the resulting render tree]

I'm guessing flutter has cached the old code and never bothered replacing it with the new one, but I am not sure how it's Hot Reload was implemented. Anyways, I don't think that it is necessary to load the old cache when we have already performed a full rebuild.

Comment: I just spent ridiculous amount of time figuring out that in Android Studio you have menu with two main.dart files, they have different icons. I had just to change it from main.dart to another main.dart

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You can run `flutter clean`.

But that's most likely a problem with your IDE or similar, as flutter run creates a brand new apk. And hot reload push only modifications.

Try running your app using the command line `flutter run` and then press `r` or `R` for respectively hot-reload and full-reload.

Comment: I've encountered this when running from the command line, so it's not an IDE problem.

Comment: Flutter clean did it for me too. But shouldn't Flutter do this automatically? In what scenario would we want it to run old code?

Comment: @ThinkDigital Its a bug that is investigated, but they have hard time reproducing it

Comment: So it doesn&#39;t happen to everyone? And wouldn&#39;t it be simple to run a Flutter clean? These files have to be laying around somewhere... Going to do some research next time it happens.

Comment: Turns out flutter doesn't  rebuild the app-debug.apk. Otherwise, flutter doesn't delete the old app-debug.apk and launches it

Comment: Just to add to this answer sometimes if it is fault of dependencies you should also clear their cache by running in terminal `flutter pub cache repair`.

Answer (score 49):

If in android studio 
Tools->Flutter->Clean

[image]

Answer (score 11):

There are basically *3 alternatives* to cleaning everything that you could try:

- `flutter clean` will delete the `/build` folder.
- Manually delete the `/build` folder, which is essentially the same as `flutter clean`.
- Or, as @Rémi Roudsselet pointed out: restart your IDE, as it might be caching some older error logs and locking everything up.

Comment: Restarting my IDE after have running "flutter clean" , then, " flutter pub get" did it for me.

Answer (score 8):

Besides running `flutter clean`... The IDE sometimes has its own cache,
[image: Android invalidate cache]

If that still does not work try deleting the app from the emulator or using a new emulator. I believe the app itself might be the one caching part of the application.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to automate running the clean before you debug your code.
(Warning, this runs everytime you hit the button, even for hot restart)

1. First, find the Run > Edit Configurations Menu
2. Click the External tool '+' icon under Before launch: External tool,
   Activate tool window.
3. Run External Tool
4. Configure it like so. Put
       the working directory as a directory in your project.

[image: Edit Configurations.]
[image: Configurations]

[image: Run External Tool]
[image: Add Flutter Clean]

Answer (score 2):

you may find it useful if you delete the `.pubcache` inside your flutter sdk directory.

Comment: This saves my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `flutter clean` and that didn't work for me. Then I went to wipe the emulator's data and voila, the cached issue was gone. If you have Android Studio you can launch the AVD Manager by following this [Create and Manage virtual machine](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds). Otherwise you can wipe the emulator's data using the emulator.exe command line that's included in the android SDK. Simply follow this instructions here [Start the emulator from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline).

Comment: I still having this problem after `flutter clean` and also wipe emulator

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with mine.

New to Flutter. I'm using VS build-in terminal to do `flutter run`, to run the app in iPhone. It gives me error `Error when reading 'lib/student_model.dart': No such file...`, which is an old code version in my code. I have changed it to `lib/model/student_model.dart`.

And I search this line 'lib/student_model.dart'`in the project, it appears file`kernel_snapshot.d` containing it. So, it build the project with old code version.

For me, `Flutter clean` is not working. Restart VS fix the issue, not sure the problem is due to Flutter or VS?

And I'm wondering if there is some command to just build flutter project without run?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and i found out that I was having two terminals in visual studio code, On first terminal it was already running my flutter project and on the other terminal I was running different solutions shared in this thread. Due to this reason no solution was working for me. So there are two ways you can solve this problem.
1- Restart visual studio code (it will automatically close the terminals)
2- Stop the terminal in which flutter project is already running and then run flutter clean command.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to clean cache in flutter

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can delete the /build folder under your /app-project folder manually if you cannot run flutter command.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score -4):

open your terminal in IDE type flutter clean and press Enter then hot Reload the project again

Comment: I don't understand why this answer gets so many negative votes. In essence it is correct. it just needs a little more explanation.

Comment: @Aldo: I imagine because it effectively reiterates what the top-voted answers already said several years before, and thus doesn't really add much to the conversation.