# Flutter throws Invalid arguments(s) error when starting the app after upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart

I upgraded flutter and and run my app, but it won't start and throws invalid arguments error.

I tried switching from dev and master channels and run flutter doctor on the terminal, but problem persists.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in feedback...                            1.0s
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/flutter ( 6956): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6956): The following ArgumentError was thrown attaching to the render tree:
I/flutter ( 6956): Invalid argument(s)
I/flutter ( 6956): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 6956): #0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:260:57)
I/flutter ( 6956): #1      new _MainModel&Model&AuthModel&ResponsesModel (package:Feedback/scoped-models/main.dart:10:57)
I/flutter ( 6956): #2      new _MainModel&Model&AuthModel&ResponsesModel&UtilityModel (package:Feedback/scoped-models/main.dart)
I/flutter ( 6956): #3      new _MainModel&Model&AuthModel&ResponsesModel&UtilityModel&InternetModel (package:Feedback/scoped-models/main.dart)
I/flutter ( 6956): #4      new MainModel (package:Feedback/scoped-models/main.dart)
I/flutter ( 6956): #5      new MyAppState (package:Feedback/main.dart:23:27)
I/flutter ( 6956): #6      MyApp.createState (package:Feedback/main.dart:18:12)
I/flutter ( 6956): #7      new StatefulElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3989:25)
I/flutter ( 6956): #8      StatefulWidget.createElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:802:38)
I/flutter ( 6956): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3082:40)
I/flutter ( 6956): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter ( 6956): #11     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:939:16)
I/flutter ( 6956): #12     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:910:5)
I/flutter ( 6956): #13     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:856:17)
I/flutter ( 6956): #14     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2320:19)
I/flutter ( 6956): #15     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:855:13)
I/flutter ( 6956): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:736:7)
I/flutter ( 6956): #17     runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:786:7)
I/flutter ( 6956): #18     main (package:Feedback/main.dart:12:16)
I/flutter ( 6956): #19     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:216:25)
I/flutter ( 6956): #24     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:208:5)
I/flutter ( 6956): #25     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
I/flutter ( 6956): #26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
I/flutter ( 6956): (elided 4 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 6956): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/EGL_emulation( 6956): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa442fc0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9fb5e310)
```

Comment: Did you run "flutter clean"?

Comment: Do `flutter clean`, run the app again, if the problem persists, quit the app, and rerun again. It will solve the issue basically. Or it is some package which is outdated.

Comment: @Alok Yes i did flutter clean but it didn't. I later realized i had wrongly  introduced Authorization headers in my http requests and that's what was causing the problem. Thanks all its now solved.

Comment: Great to hear about that @Loki, I hope you do not steal the space stone XD

Comment: :D "space stone" @Alok

Comment: For others who stumble upon this as I did, be sure you aren't calling a bad `setState` with invalid values. This caused a similar issue for me.

Comment: @Loki 
Sir I'm facing something like this. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

As what have previously pointed out in the comments, running [`flutter clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279379/) has been suggested because it usually solves build issues. The command clears the build cache of the project and trying to run the app again should rebuild the project and potentially clears out any issues. But in this case, it seems that you've found the cause is something else.

Going forward, it will also be helpful to provide a [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for folks to be able to replicate the given issue.