# Flutter :- Failed to build iOS app using flutter run iOS command . ** BUILD FAILED **

Tags: ios, flutter, build

Flutter : Log Details => Xcode build done. Failed to build iOS app, can anyone help me out for solving ios related errors while I am running flutter run iOS...

```
 Xcode build done.                                           21.9s
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        ** BUILD FAILED **
    Xcode's output:
    ↳
        === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftSwiftOnoneSupport'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
        ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreAudio'
        Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

**flutter doctor -v**

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.6
>   18G87, locale en-IN)
>       • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /Users/btlmac/www/flutter
>       • Framework revision 68587a0916 (10 weeks ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
>       • Engine revision b863200c37
>       • Dart version 2.5.0
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 28.0.3)
>       • Android SDK at /Users/btlmac/Library/Android/sdk
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
>       • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/btlmac/Library/Android/sdk
>       • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
>       • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
>       • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>       • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
>       • CocoaPods version 1.8.4
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
>       • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
>       • Flutter plugin version 29.0.1
>       • Dart plugin version 173.4700
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.40.1)
>       • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
>       • Flutter extension version 3.6.0
>
> [✓] Connected device (2 available)
>       • Lenovo X3a40 • 5453f602                             • android-arm64 • Android 6.0.1 (API 23)
>       • iPhone X     • A70C38B1-AE7B-4EF5-B570-8872C81C147B • ios           • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)
>
> • No issues found!

Comment: run `flutter doctor -v` command in your terminal and add output to your question

Comment: yes, already added..please check

Answer (score 0):

Running [`flutter clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49279547) usually solves build issues. The command clears the build cache of the project and trying to run the app again should rebuild the project and potentially clears out any errors.

If you're still having issues, it will also be helpful to provide a [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for folks to be able to replicate the given issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Runner > Info > Configurations like this & follow this [Flutter Run with Hot Reload on Real iOS Devices guide](https://medium.com/@aristidios/flutter-hot-reload-%EF%B8%8F-on-real-ios-device-iphone-ipad-with-m1-mac-intel-fa9396202a02)

[image: Runner > Info > Configs]

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Xcode to see what is causing the problem. Head to your project folder, open the ios folder, run the `Runner.xcworkspace` file, and run it from Xcode. If you have any issue that you cannot fix, ask it.

The `flutter clean` command is another solution that you can test. After `flutter clean` make sure that you will download and apply the SDKs again.