# How to Force Delete App from Emulator for every Flutter build

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I want to force Android Studio to delete the previous build every time I rebuild.

Currently for whatever reason it does not delete the previous build and simply runs that old version. If I manually delete first it works as expected and runs the new build.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the build, just using this terminal command `rm -rf build`

But perhaps in your case, try using `flutter clean` is enough. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Quang. Is there any way to run this command automatically at the start of every build?
(no, flutter clean is not enough)

Comment: @DanHorton check this reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/52730971/1682677. It's similar to your case, add a macro to remove the build folder.

Comment: Thanks Quang, this will save me a LOT of frustration! Previously even after flutter clean it was still loading and old version of my app. This rm -rf build command should be integrated into flutter clean

Comment: So could you make a feature request for flutter team via their git ? It would be a contribution for the flutter community :)

Answer (score 0):

Must build again with
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
and run
flutter install
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O66OA.png)

Comment: before you run flutter install, you must run debugging