# Flutter iOS app won't build after adding Google Maps package in pubspec.yaml

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, flutter, dart

Flutter iOS app won't build after adding Google Maps package in pubspec.yaml
The app builds fine after removing Google Maps package (https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)
Please help!!

The error log:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 Plus in debug mode...

Running pod install...                                              7.2s
Running Xcode build...

└─Compiling, linking and signing...                         4.0s
Xcode build done.                                           49.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
2020-08-14 10:36:17.831 xcodebuild[5254:93706] warning:  The file reference for
"Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h" is a member of multiple
groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only
the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).
If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the
same path.
2020-08-14 10:36:17.831 xcodebuild[5254:93706] warning:  The file reference for
"Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h" is a member of multiple groups
("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If
you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
path.
2020-08-14 10:36:17.831 xcodebuild[5254:93706] warning:  The file reference for
"Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h" is a member of multiple groups
("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If
you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
path.
2020-08-14 10:36:17.831 xcodebuild[5254:93706] warning:  The file reference for
"Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h" is a member of multiple groups
("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If
you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
path.
2020-08-14 10:36:17.831 xcodebuild[5254:93706] warning:  The file reference for
"Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h" is a member of multiple groups
("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If
you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
path.
2020-08-14 10:36:17.831 xcodebuild[5254:93706] warning:  The file reference for
"Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h" is a member of multiple groups
("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If
you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
path.
2020-08-14 10:36:17.831 xcodebuild[5254:93706] warning:  The file reference for
"Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h" is a member of multiple groups
("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If
you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same
path.
2020-08-14 10:36:17.831 xcodebuild[5254:93706] warning:  The file reference for
"Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h" is a member of multiple
groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only
the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).
If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the
same path.
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/chrisflection/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pdfview-1.0.3+2/io
s/Classes/FlutterPDFView.m:25:5: warning: 'FLTPDFViewController' is only available on iOS 11.0 or
newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
FLTPDFViewController* pdfviewController = [[FLTPDFViewController alloc] initWithFrame:frame
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from
/Users/chrisflection/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pdfview-1.0.3+2/io
s/Classes/FlutterPDFView.m:4:
/Users/chrisflection/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pdfview-1.0.3+2/io
s/Classes/FlutterPDFView.h:11:12: note: 'FLTPDFViewController' has been marked as being introduced in
iOS 11.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 9.0.0
@interface FLTPDFViewController : NSObject <FlutterPlatformView, PDFViewDelegate>
^
/Users/chrisflection/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pdfview-1.0.3+2/io
s/Classes/FlutterPDFView.m:25:5: note: enclose 'FLTPDFViewController' in an @available check to
silence this warning
FLTPDFViewController* pdfviewController = [[FLTPDFViewController alloc] initWithFrame:frame
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/chrisflection/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pdfview-1.0.3+2/io
s/Classes/FlutterPDFView.m:25:49: warning: 'FLTPDFViewController' is only available on iOS 11.0 or
newer [-Wunguarded-availability-new]
FLTPDFViewController* pdfviewController = [[FLTPDFViewController alloc] initWithFrame:frame
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from
/Users/chrisflection/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pdfview-1.0.3+2/io
s/Classes/FlutterPDFView.m:4:
/Users/chrisflection/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pdfview-1.0.3+2/io
s/Classes/FlutterPDFView.h:11:12: note: 'FLTPDFViewController' has been marked as being introduced in
iOS 11.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 9.0.0
@interface FLTPDFViewController : NSObject <FlutterPlatformView, PDFViewDelegate>
^
/Users/chrisflection/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pdfview-1.0.3+2/io
s/Classes/FlutterPDFView.m:25:49: note: enclose 'FLTPDFViewController' in an @available check to
silence this warning
FLTPDFViewController* pdfviewController = [[FLTPDFViewController alloc] initWithFrame:frame
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
ld: targeted OS version does not support use of thread local variables in
__ZN9GMSx_absl9GMSx_Cord9InlineRep10AppendTreeEPNS_13cord_internal12GMSx_CordRepE for architecture
x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid
Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target
'flutter_pdfview' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid
Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target
'flutter_pdfview' from project 'Pods')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/chrisflection/Desktop/Mischief.nosync/mischief_flutter_app/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Object
ive-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h (in target 'TOCropViewController'
from project 'Pods')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/chrisflection/Desktop/Mischief.nosync/mischief_flutter_app/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Object
ive-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
'Pods')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/chrisflection/Desktop/Mischief.nosync/mischief_flutter_app/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Object
ive-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from
project 'Pods')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/chrisflection/Desktop/Mischief.nosync/mischief_flutter_app/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Object
ive-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
'Pods')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/chrisflection/Desktop/Mischief.nosync/mischief_flutter_app/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Object
ive-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
'Pods')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/chrisflection/Desktop/Mischief.nosync/mischief_flutter_app/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Object
ive-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/chrisflection/Desktop/Mischief.nosync/mischief_flutter_app/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Object
ive-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
'Pods')
warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
/Users/chrisflection/Desktop/Mischief.nosync/mischief_flutter_app/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Object
ive-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h (in target
'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements
use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target
'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus.

This is my pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  image_cropper: ^1.2.3
  table_calendar: ^2.2.3
  substring_highlight: ^0.1.2
  intl: ^0.16.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+5
  image_picker: ^0.6.7
  mime_type: ^0.3.2
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.0+10
  path_provider: ^1.6.5
  pdf_flutter: ^1.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  multi_image_picker: ^4.6.9
  outline_material_icons: ^0.1.1
  fading_edge_scrollview: ^1.1.4
  sticky_headers: ^0.1.8+1
  flutter_tindercard: ^0.1.9
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.30
```

Comment: hey, did you got any solution for this?

Comment: @VickySingh nope... I eventually removed the google map plugin

Answer (score 0):

I've added google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.30 on my app, but I didn't encounter any issues running the app on iOS. I suggest running a [flutter clean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49279547) to clear the build cache and try running the app again. If you're still having issues, run `flutter doctor` to check for any errors or warnings.