# Local files not opening on iOS simulator after restart

Tags: ios, file, flutter

I am trying to read and write local files in Flutter and till then everything is OK.

But then when I restart the simulator, I get the error:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
Cannot open file, path = '/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5A353A88-24B3-469C-9C9B-D2542FCAE084/data/Containers/Data/Application/8A33D1B7-4647-4255-A759-65835BE2DBE6/Documents/images/FzIkrXlx2OheqTzKp1AfffGFxMm1/savedPng/2020-08-17T23:57:11.239738Z.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
Cannot open file, path = '' (OS Error: Bad address, errno = 14)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '' (OS Error: Bad address, errno = 14)
```

The strange thing is that I have a file in which I save all the paths for the images, and it is OK to read it.

I just save some images with DateTime.now() name and when I use Directory(path).list() I get them there:

```
flutter: /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5A353A88-24B3-469C-9C9B-D2542FCAE084/data/Containers/Data/Application/95822A0C-C6E5-4A01-8267-04DC0054B57C/Documents/images/FzIkrXlx2OheqTzKp1AfffGFxMm1/savedPng/local_mask_files
flutter: /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5A353A88-24B3-469C-9C9B-D2542FCAE084/data/Containers/Data/Application/95822A0C-C6E5-4A01-8267-04DC0054B57C/Documents/images/FzIkrXlx2OheqTzKp1AfffGFxMm1/savedPng/2020-08-15T06:35:21.536337Z.png
flutter: /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5A353A88-24B3-469C-9C9B-D2542FCAE084/data/Containers/Data/Application/95822A0C-C6E5-4A01-8267-04DC0054B57C/Documents/images/FzIkrXlx2OheqTzKp1AfffGFxMm1/savedPng/2020-08-15T06:37:47.983926Z.png
flutter: /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5A353A88-24B3-469C-9C9B-D2542FCAE084/data/Containers/Data/Application/95822A0C-C6E5-4A01-8267-04DC0054B57C/Documents/images/FzIkrXlx2OheqTzKp1AfffGFxMm1/savedPng/2020-08-17T23:57:11.239738Z.png
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: doing clear cache? link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279379/how-to-clear-flutters-build-cache

Comment: It is not this.. the problem is that Image.file() does not recognize the file.

Comment: can you try to save this image w.r.t. id ? like http://www.google.com/abc/121311 (save this image as 121311.png and try to reterive with this id

Comment: I had similar Error when I use get External Directory in IOS with `path_provider` . Do you use ?

`getExternalStorageDirectory().`
`getExternalStorageDirectories(type: type)`
`getExternalCacheDirectories()`

Comment: @theCaptainXgod  please read my comment.

Comment: @Sajjad I am trying to create a system where users can save their drafts locally, for example, a video locally. I am trying to use getApplicationSupportDirectory(). Still, even though I am copying the picked video to my custom directory, the file exists there but in the next restart, the file can't be opened. Did this answer your question?