# Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, flutter-packages

I added the package 'qr_code_scanner: ^0.5.1' into my pubspec.yaml.

After restarting my app, the following error appeared:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner- 
0.5.1\android\build.gradle' line: 39

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':qr_code_scanner'.
> Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments 
[build_983ew3001pu1n91tvzyoag4vc$_run_closure2$_closure7@3a00d2ee] on object of type 
com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My flutter doctor:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNvxP.png)

I really don't know what caused the error.

Thank you for all reply!

Comment: can you try running `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, and then try building again?

Comment: To be honest I don't know where to run these commands. I just used the buttons in IntelliJ for `flutter pug get`. So where do I run `flutter clean`.

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043364/12555423

Comment: Tanks, but I still get the error.

Comment: what is the version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` under `buildscript > dependencies` in `android/build.gradle`?

Comment: My gradle version is 3.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- stop project
- delete the folder (C:\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\qr_code_scanner-
  0.5.1
- change to version   "qr_code_scanner: ^0.4.0",
- run flutter pub get
- run project again
- for my case it worked

Comment: Also you need to change minSdkVersion to atleast 20 inside android/app/build.gradle