# Firebase Authentication UserCredential

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

The UserCredential keep showing message:

Undefined class 'UserCredential'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'UserCredential'.dartundefined_class

I import :

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ;
```

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_database: "^6.0.0"
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.5
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
```

and this the code in the main:

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    print('The password provided is too weak.');
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    print('The account already exists for that email.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Comment: Did you do `Pub Get` in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: yes and it is the same problem

Comment: really strange one... Is it a runtime error or is flagged by the syntax?

Comment: flagged by the syntax

Comment: Crazy... Are you sure this line `import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ;` is in the same file on the top?

Comment: how can I know?

Comment: That import `import package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ;` needs to be written in the same file where you have your code that uses `UserCredential`. In other words, the import is written just before the class that is performing the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: yes it is in the same file :)

Comment: I found the reason ;0)  I am writing an answer now

Comment: give me 2 minutes ;0)

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**
In your `dependencies:` you are importing an old version of `firebase_core` that only works with an old version of `firebase_auth`(non null safety)

```
  firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_auth: "^0.20.1"
```

**The solution:**
You will need to change to the most recent version, like the following:

```
  firebase_core: "^1.7.0"   //** CHANGE THIS LINE
  firebase_auth: "^3.1.3"
```

Don't forget to do `pub get`

More details [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/)

Comment: Basically, you need to use either the 2 old versions or the 2 new ones but can't mix. Hope it works ;0)

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: Grrrr.... The rest looks good to me. Can you show all your code from where you are using `UserCredential`

Comment: I think you cannot try to create the users before you call `runApp`.   [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/runApp.html)  Can you move your Auth code inside the `build` of the `Mudrek`  class?

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: Crazy... I have the same code and it is working properly in my project. Are you sure you did `Pub get` properly?

Comment: Is there any other error before the UserCredential one?

Comment: yes me too I tried the same code on another project and it is working maybe there is a problem in the project it self

Comment: FirebaseAuthException it give same error

Comment: No doubt that flutter is not properly reading this package `import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ;`   Ok last attempt: Try a `flutter clean`   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279379/how-to-clear-flutters-build-cache)

Comment: still the same problem :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that... I am out of ideas... I will follow this question. Please, let me know if you end up finding an answer... Good luck to you ;0)