# flutter error: Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

when I am going to install my project in my mobile device then I got error to chenge compileSDKVersion 33.

After changing my compileSDKVersion 33 from compileSDKVersion 32,
Then I got this error Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

This is my build.gradle file.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "org.mycwc"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'

}
```

I got this error after changing compileSDKVersion 33 from compileSDKVersion 32.

```
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:280: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCachePath(options.appCachePath);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:494: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:504: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:515: error: cannot find symbol
        settings.setAppCachePath(ctx.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
                ^
  symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:517: error: cannot find symbol
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:521: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:767: error: cannot find symbol
      settings.setAppCachePath(newOptions.appCachePath);
              ^
  symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59011226/2649154

Answer (score 3):

- I fixed the issue with :

1. upgrade my gradle version to `7.1.4`
2. upgrade gradle wrapper to `7.4`
3. upgrade kotlin version to `1.6.10`

**Ref:** https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1299#issuecomment-1240159079

Answer (score 2):

Checkout your gradle plugin is compatible with your gradle version or not.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

I have faced the same error when my gradle version was **6.7.1** while my plugin was **4.1.0**. Updating the plugin to **4.2.0** solved it for me.

The gradle plugin version is located on **android/build.gradle** as classpath **'com.android.tools.build:gradle:{your version}'** on the dependencies.

The gradle version is located on **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** under distributionUrl.

Hopes it will help you.

Comment: worked  successfully