# Could not load compiled classes for build file '\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_inappwebview-5.7.2+3\android\build.gradle' from cache

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, webview

My project was running successfully but after sudden power down of my pc, when I try to run the project the following error is shown
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_inappwebview'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\ibrahim42386\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_inappwebview-5.7.2+3\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_inappwebview' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_inappwebview' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cache issue, if any package was incompatible then it will through the bug at Pub get time. So try to clean the Cache of Flutter .
try this: [clean Cache in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279379/how-to-clear-flutters-build-cache)